# Crypt large amount of data in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt, large-data-volumes, large-data

I develop a software which have to crypt data before to send it to another instance of the same soft (which have to decrypt it of course). I first use openssl_public_encrypt / openssl_private_decrypt, like that

```
foreach(str_split($sData, MAXSIZE) as $sChunk)
{
    if( ! @openssl_public_encrypt($sChunk, $crypted, $sPublicKey)) throw new Exception('openssl_public_encrypt');
    $aCrypted[] = $crypted;
}
```

and

```
$sResult = '';
foreach($aCrypted['data'] as $ct => $sChunkCrypted)
{
    if( ! openssl_private_decrypt($sChunkCrypted, $sChunk, $sPrivateKey)) throw new Exception("decrypt");
    $sResult .= $sChunk;
}
```

because the chunk of data to encrypt can't be larger than the key, but the decrypt part take too much time (xdebug tells me this is calls to openssl_private_decrypt() which take all the time).

I try with symmetric algorithms mcrypt_decrypt/MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 (with openssl to crypt the key) but it's worse. What can I do to transfert large amount of data in a secure way? Files are CSV (text) and are put on a SSH/SFTP server, they have to be crypted.

Thanks,
Cédric

Comment: Why not use [SCP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php)?

Comment: Because I need to crypt the data, even if the copy between servers is secured, and SFTP is not less secure than SCP. Right?

Comment: Sure, SFTP is fine too. If you need to encrypt the stored data, why not do it at the filesystem level? If performance is an issue, this should be much faster than anything you could cook up in PHP. If that sounds like something you want to explore, check out [eCryptfs](https://launchpad.net/ecryptfs).

Comment: In fact severals servers put and get files on the storage server (kind of messaging box), and only the addressee of a file is allowed to read it. So asymmetric encryption seems to be a good choice.

Comment: This is possible with eCryptfs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SCP or SFTP. They'll use SSL for the actual data transmission, so you'll get the encryption stuff automatically. If you need to  STORE the files in a crypted state, then you'll have to use mcrypt and its friends to do the encryption for you.

As for the "data has to be smaller than the key" only applies in a one-time-pad situation. Modern ciphers essentially always have keys that are smaller than the data being encrypted.... think of a large RAR or ZIP file - multi-megabytes of data, but a key (password) that's only a few characters in size.

Comment: SCP/SFTP is for the transfert, but data have to be crypted if the storage server is compromised. Mcrypt is slower than asymetric keys (but I maybe misuse it). And "data has to be smaller than the key" is still right for the openssl lib used by PHP. exec() is not always availables on my customers' servers, and I bet GPG/PGP or ZIP/RAR/GZ/BZ2/... crypt data by small chunks, as I do.
If I am completly wrong, please help me to understand how to do this according to my needs.